# How i can embed photoswipe

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

Here's the issue:

I upload photoswipe to my server and give it a subdomain to use it inside of an iframe. 
After i did that photoswipe open but when i click on the thumbnails the pictures open fullscreen 
not on Jquery at all. Is like the library is not working

I research online for the same issue but i couldn't find anything if somebody can help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting photoswipe in an `iframe`?

Comment: Beyond why you're putting iframe in photoswipe, show us how you invoke photoswipe, and show us the elements structure.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? Are you sure jQuery and photoswipe are loading?

Comment: The reason why im using photoswipe inside of an iframe is because im using HYPE for mac to develop a page so i use the iframe option. But i would love any other sugestions im a nube coding.